# how do I make ng-token-auth apiUri config dynamic so that it can be changed in settings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework, devise

I have an Ionic/Angular app, and I am using `ng-token-auth` for authentication.  The base part of the authentication url is configured via a `$provider`. As a result I don't seem to be able to set the configuration on the fly because:

1. `$providers` can not be called after the angular has started.  So they can be changed on the fly
2. I could save the setting in the database, and restart the app, but the database is not accessible until after `angular` has started, so it is too late to call the `ng-token-auth $provider`

The only solution I see is to store the settings in `localstorage`, which is accessible before angular starts and read them from there after a restart.

I would prefer to logout, change the `apiUri` and then login again without a restart

Has anyone else tried to dynamically change the `apiUri`